# First `li` element in second `ul` column has no margin?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a top margin to every `li` element in a `ul` element that has the css property `column-count: 2` set. For some reason, the margin works for every `li` element except the first element in the second column:

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could you elaborate? Maybe I don't understand how CSS margins work, but I've never run into an issue where one element's margins are ignored because of its position relative to a sibling element. The inspector even shows that the margin is being applied.

Comment: yes i know it's not easy to explain, but am searching for the exact reference to use in order to explain this particular behavior ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just using margin-bottom instead? Also apply 10px padding to your ul in order to achieve the same.

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and you need to say padding ;) as not only margin-bottom will fix the issue, the issue is still there

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `display` property of the list items to `inline-block` and the `width` to `100%` to remedy this

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion @Troels gave is a good option. You can look into padding as an option too:

```
li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```